# Vector derivative of $f(x)=(A+x \mathbb{1}^T)^{-1} b$

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I am trying to find a vector derivative  of $f(x)=(A+x \mathbb{1}^T)^{-1} b$  where  $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}^n$.  Assume that all vectors a column. Also  $\mathbb{1}$ is a vector of all ones.

I was trying to use the properties of vector derivatives that can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus).
However, I could find a property I need.

I think it should be some thing of the form 
\begin{align}
(A+x \mathbb{1}^T)^{-1} b \mathbb{1}^T (A+x \mathbb{1}^T)^{-1}
\end{align}

Comment: so I understand the question, if you start with $n=2$ you have $f(x)=(A_{11}+x)b_1+(A_{12}+x)b_2+(A_{21}+x)b_1+(A_{22}+x)b_2$ giving derivative $df/dx=2b_1+2b_2$

Comment: @phdmba7of12 there is an inverse in the expression.

Comment: ah ... okay ... need to include the inverse

Comment: Wouldn't you need an overall $-$ sign?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's consider a more general problem by replacing $1$ with any constant column vector $c$. Then$$0=\partial_ib_j=\partial_i[(A_{jk}+x_jc_k)f_k]=(A_{jk}+x_jc_k)\partial_if_k+\delta_{ij}c_kf_k.$$The matrix $\partial f$ of $_{ik}$ index $\partial_if_k$ satisfies$$0=\partial f(A^T+cx^T)+(c\cdot f)I\implies\partial f=-(c\cdot f)(A^T+cx^T)^{-1}=-(A+xc^T)^{-1}bc^T(A^T+cx^T)^{-1}.$$

Comment: Thanks. I really like your notation.

Comment: Quick question:  If we instead we consider $f(x)=(A+cx^T)^{-1}b$, then the result is $-(A+c x^T)^{-1} cb^T(A^T+xc^T )^{-1}$, right?

Comment: @Lisa Feel free to check.

Answer (score 0):

$
\def\a{\alpha}\def\b{\beta}\def\g{\gamma}\def\t{\theta}
\def\l{\lambda}\def\s{\sigma}\def\e{\varepsilon}
\def\n{\nabla}\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{\partial}
\def\E{{\cal E}}\def\F{{\cal F}}\def\G{{\cal G}}
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\diag#1{\operatorname{diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\operatorname{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
$For typing convenience, define the matrix variable
and its various differentials
$$\eqalign{
&M = \LR{A+x\o^T} \\
&dM = dx\,\o^T \\
&dM^{-1} = -M^{-1}\,dM\,M^{-1} \\
}$$
Write the function in terms of this new variable,
then calculate its differential and gradient
$$\eqalign{
f &= {M^{-1}}b \\
df &= -M^{-1}(dM)\;\c{M^{-1}b} \\
 &= -M^{-1}\LR{dx\,\o^T}\c{f} \\
 &= -\LR{\o^Tf}M^{-1}\,dx \\
\grad fx &= -\LR{f^T\o}M^{-1} \\
\\
}$$