# Vector derivative of $ f(x)= (A+B\operatorname{diag}(x))^{-1} b$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, jacobian

How to find a vector derivative with respect to $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$  of 
\begin{align}f(x)=  (A+B \operatorname{diag}(x))^{-1} b
\end{align}
where   $\operatorname{diag}(x)$ is a diagonal matrix where $x$ is a main diagonal, $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, $B\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, $b \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

This question is similar to what I have asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3478951/vector-derivative-of-fx-ax-mathbb1t-1-b).  However, there are some differences with matrix multiplication that lead to some confusion for me.

I am also wondering if this can be shown using $\epsilon$-definition of the derivative.

Comment: The typographical difference between {\rm diag} and \operatorname{diag} was extremely conspicuous in this posting before my edit. Two things should be observed. The first is the difference seen here below: $$ \begin{align} & B{\rm diag}(x) \\ & B\operatorname{diag}(x) \end{align} $$ The other is the difference seen here below between B\operatorname{diag}(x) and B\operatorname{diag}x (specifically, look immediately to the right of both occurrences of "diag" below): $$ \begin{align} & B\operatorname{diag}(x) \\ & B\operatorname{diag}x \end{align} $$

Comment: Thank you. I was not aware of "peratorname{}". Thank you. It looks much cleaner! I will use this in the future.

Comment: Bad choice of notation. $b$ should be renamed $c$. What if I want to mention the columns of $B$? I cannot use lowercase because it's already taken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain the derivative by the chain rule. Let
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{ll}
\cr\Phi\colon &GL_n({\mathbb R})\to {\mathbb R}^{n\times n}\cr
&U \mapsto U^{-1}
\end{array}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{l}\cr
g \colon &{\mathbb R}^n\to {\mathbb R}^{n\times n}\cr
 &x \mapsto A + B \operatorname{diag}(x)
\end{array}
\end{equation}
Then $\Phi'(U)\cdot H = -U^{-1} H U^{-1}$ and $g'(x).h = B \operatorname{diag}(h)$, hence by the chain rule
\begin{equation}
f'(x)\cdot h =- ( A + B \operatorname{diag}(x))^{-1} B \operatorname{diag}(h)( A + B \operatorname{diag}(x))^{-1} b
\end{equation}
In terms of partial derivatives, it means that
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} =- ( A + B \operatorname{diag}(x))^{-1} B E_{i,i}( A + B \operatorname{diag}(x))^{-1} b
\end{equation}
where $E_{i, i}$ is the matrix of which all terms are zero but the term of at position $(i, i)$ which value is $1$, or equivalently $E_{i, i} = e_i e_i^T$ where $e_i$ is the i-th basis column vector.

In particular, one sees that $e_i^T ( A + B \operatorname{diag}(x))^{-1} b$ is a scalar, the $i$-th component of $f(x)$ and it follows easily that the Jacobian matrix of $f$, which columns are the vectors $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$ must be
\begin{equation}
\partial f = - ( A + B \operatorname{diag}(x))^{-1} B \operatorname{diag}(f(x))
\end{equation}

Comment: Should there be a transpose for the derivative of $\Phi'(U)$???

Comment: If you prefer partial derivatives, you can write $\displaystyle\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial u_{i, j}} = - U^{-1} e_i e_j^T U^{-1}$. Note that $\Phi$ is a function of the $n^2$ matrix coefficients. When I write $\phi'(U)\cdot H$ it means the derivative of $\Phi$ at $U$ applied to $H$. The dot is not a matrix product.

Comment: Ok. Thank. So what would matrix $\partial f$ be ?

Comment: Excellent question. See my edits above.

Comment: Very interesting. Thanks.  I was't not expecting that. I suppose that re-writing $\operatorname{diag}\left( (A+B \operatorname{diag}(x))^{-1} b \right)$ in terms of  $(A+B \operatorname{diag}(x))^{-1}$ and $b$ without the outside $diag()$ is difficult?

Comment: Well, I don't know a better form. You could perhaps give names to the coefficients of the matrix $(A + B\operatorname{diag}(x))^{-1}$ and use these names but why do you want to re-write it?

Comment: I was thinking it would be nice to simplify the term $\operatorname{diag}(A+B\operatorname{diag}(x))^{-1}b)$.  The nesting of $\operatorname{diag}$ looks unusually to me.  However, it is what it is.

Comment: I don't fully understand your notation, but $\Phi ' (U) \cdot H =  -U^{-1}HU^{-1}$ is making me very nervous. Are you certain it wouldn't be something like $-(U^{-1})^THU$?

Comment: @Taw This notation is used sometimes in higher dimensional spaces. $\Phi$ is differentiable because there is a linear map $L$ such that $\Phi(U + H) = \Phi(U) + L(H) + o(H)$ when $H\to 0$. Several notations exist for $L(H)$ such as $D\Phi(U)(H)$ or $\Phi'(U)(H)$ or even $\Phi'(U)\cdot H$ to emphasize linearity. There is no transposed matrix in this derivative.

Answer (score 1):

Write the function as $\;f = M^{-1}b$

where
$$\eqalign{
&M=A+BX,\quad X={\rm Diag}(x),\quad F={\rm Diag}(f) \\
&Xf= Fx = f\odot x\qquad(\odot{\rm \,denotes\,Hadamard\,Product}) \\
}$$
then calculate the differential and gradient of the function
$$\eqalign{
df &= dM^{-1}b \\&= -M^{-1}\,dM\,M^{-1}b \\
 &= -M^{-1}\,dM\,f \\
 &= -M^{-1}(B\;dX)\,f \\
 &= -M^{-1}BF\,dx\\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}
 &= -M^{-1}BF 
 \;=\; -\Big(A+B\,{\rm Diag}(x)\Big)^{-1}B\;{\rm Diag}(f) \\
}$$

#### Update

The following derivation was requested by a commenter. 

Write the definition of the matrix inverse and take its differential.
$$\eqalign{
I &= M^{-1}M \\
0 &= dM^{-1}M + M^{-1}dM \\
  &= dM^{-1} + M^{-1}dM\,M^{-1} \\
dM^{-1}
  &= -M^{-1}dM\,M^{-1} \\
}$$

Comment: I have a few small questions. Why is $ d M^{-1} = dM M^{-1}$?

Comment: The answer had been updated with a derivation.

Comment: Thanks this very clear to me know.   One more question. Can u explain going from $dX f$ to $F dx$?

Comment: @Lisa Because both expressions equate to $(f\odot dx)\,$ and the Hadamard product is commutative.